# Optimization (in C language): Many function calls vs One function call

Tags: c, optimization, function-calls

For example, I want to create a function (`insertNode`) that adds nodes to a list. Is it faster to call `insertNode` every time I want to add a node, or to store all the nodes in an array, and call the `insertNode` just one time, by passing the array as the argument and let the function do the rest?

Code example:

```
typedef struct Data {
    int *myArray;             //the array where all integers are stored
    int firstAvailablePos;    //the first free position of myArray
} Data;

insertNode(Data *data, int newNum) {
    (data->myArray)[data->firstAvailablePos] = newNum;
    (data->firstAvailablePos)++;
}

alt_insertNode(Data *data, int *array, int arraySize) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
         (data->myarray)[i] = array[i];
}
```

And in `main` the two options are:

1. Many function calls

   ```
   while (...) {
       ...
       insertNode(data, newNum);
   }
   ```
2. One function call

   ```
   anArraySize = 0;
   while (...) {
       ...
       anArray[i] = newNum;
       anArraySize++;
       ...
   }
   alt_insertNode(data, anArray, anArraySize);
   ```

Comment: Posting the code to your 2 approaches would generate better specific feed-back.

Comment: It depends the individual cost of adding one item to the list, for each way you have to choose. Can you measure that? Or post code and let us calculate complexity.

Comment: I think that calling each time in this case will be more optimised, because if you'll put them in array (this is assign operation + find empty one), then when you got full table you call function that insert's nodes which eventually will be the same function as in first option but with big for loop.

Comment: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has problems:

- You use an obsolete syntax for function definitions.  The implicit return type is no longer supported in modern C code, you should specify it as `void`.
- You use extraneous parentheses that make the code look awkward.
- function `insertNode` does not check if the array pointed to by `myArray` is large enough.  You should check and reallocate the array if needed.
- function `alt_insertNode` does not check for available room, and does not update `firstAvailablePos` either.

Depending on your reallocation scheme and depending on how aggressive your compiler is allowed to optimize, it might be more efficient to insert values in batches than to insert them one by one, especially if you don't allocate the intermediary array with `malloc()`. Benchmarking your specific test cases will tell you which is more efficient.  Note however that there is substantial value in making the code as simple as possible.

Here is a more complete implementation you can use to run tests:

```
typedef struct Data {
    int *myArray;             // the array where all integers are stored
    size_t size;              // the number of int that can be stored
    size_t firstAvailablePos; // the first free position of myArray
} Data;

/* reallocating the array with a simple exponential growth */
int insertNode(Data *data, int newNum) {
    if (data->firstAvailablePos == data->size) {
        size_t newSize = (data->size < 32) ? 32 : data->size + data->size / 2;
        int *array = realloc(myArray, newSize * sizeof(*array));
        if (array == NULL)
            return -1;
        data->myArray = array;
        data->size = newSize;
    }
    data->myArray[data->firstAvailablePos++] = newNum;
    return 0;
}

int alt_insertNode(Data *data, int *array, size_t arraySize) {
    if (data->firstAvailablePos + arraySize > data->size) {
        size_t newSize = (data->size < 32) ? 32 : data->size + data->size / 2;
        while (newSize < data->firstAvailablePos + arraySize) {
            newSize += newSize / 2;
        }
        int *array = realloc(myArray, newSize * sizeof(*array));
        if (array == NULL)
            return -1;
        data->myArray = array;
        data->size = newSize;
    }
    memcpy(data->myArray + data->firstAvailablePos, array, arraySize * sizeof(*array));
    data->firstAvailablePos += arraySize;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the structure of the underlaying list implementation. If that is an array and insertNode appends it, it gets copied to a new location in memory, where there is more space available, so that the new elements also fit in. The new elements get memcpyd as well. That is fast, because it takes place in the kernel and not in your user space program.

On the other hand if you have something like a linked list in which pointers to other lists in form of arrays are getting stored. Than you would not even have to copy all the elements from the list, but just insert a single new pointer to the linked list, which points to the array with the new elements in it. That would be really fast.

The best answer from what I currently know is: It depends.

Comment: The "kernel" is definitely not involved in `memcpy`.

Comment: I partly agree, because it isn't necessarily that way and of cause depends on the implementation. But *afaik* does memcpy use syscalls and does pagecopy to improve its performance. References:

Comment: Hit return by accident.

Comment: How can I write multiline comments? http://osxr.org:8080/glibc/source/sysdeps/mach/pagecopy.h https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=string/memcpy.c http://linuxsociety.org/pub/slack-stuff/glibc-2.15/glibc-2.15/sysdeps/mach/pagecopy.h www.shakthimaan.com/downloads/hurd/kernel_interface.pdf (84) sorry for that mess.

Comment: Well, that's really interesting. I knew that kind of thing was _possible_, but I didn't know that glibc actually tried to do it. To be clear though, this only works in the special case that your source and destination regions are relative page-aligned (and you are copying at least a page or two). That would be quite rare in practice, although depending on your malloc implementation, it could actually kick in for large linear structures like `vector`, for e.g., if malloc of large amounts tended to return page-aligned regions.

Comment: BTW, you can use shift-enter to put a newline in a comment, but it won't actually show up, so essentially comments are single line. You can always "edit" your comment to fix it up though (for 5 minutes)  or delete it and post again.

Answer (score 1):

Function calling is some time more expensive than iteration. If you insert a node by calling the insertNode function it require some iteration (depend upon where you want to insert) to insert that node in the list but if you want to insert a large amount of node it require to call the function each time. which can be time expensive.

If you insert the node by putting some node into an array and at last call insertNode to copy the node of array to the list. This time insertNode will be call less time but number of interation will increase. which will not be time costly, as much as function call will be.

One thing here to noted that you require additional memory for array.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on a number of things within your program. Specifically, are the nodes to sorted by some algorithm or is order unimportant? If so, passing an array nodes or inserting individually would not make much difference  (being that sorting chunks or information and inserting a node to a sorted position should be equivalent.)

You might also consider at what point in the program the nodes need to inserted in your list. If your list employs dynamic memory, it would be necessary to to have a function to insert a node when needed sometime along the line.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the calling code looks like, but in general a short function call will have zero overhead, if it can be inlined. Creating a temporary array just avoid function-call overhead is almost certainly a mistake - but in some cases "batching" stuff up like that can avoid a bunch of per-insert overhead and may may sense.

Try both and benchmark.